# Import empty file with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large number of files that i want to import. I do this one by one with pandas. But some of them only have header text, and the actual contents is empty. This is on purpose, but I don't know which files are empty. Also, each file has a different number of columns, and the number of columns in each file is unknown. I use the following code:

```
lines = pandas.read_csv(fname, comment='#', delimiter=',', header=None)
```

Is there a way for pandas to return an empty data rame if it doesn't find any non-comment lines in a file? Or some other work around?

Thanks!

Comment: one solution would be to only use pandas if the file is actually contains some useful data. This could be checked using a for loop, and breaking the for loop as soon as it finds a useful data. But is there a way to do this with pandas itself?

Comment: So some might only have commented lines?  Meaning, no headers or data?

Comment: Yes, only commented lines, with no header or data